# What are the advantages of the different ways you can use tcolorbox together with minted? Is one to be preferred over the other?

Tags: minted, tcolorbox

I'm listing code with the minted package and drawing the box around it using the tcolorbox package. However, there are two ways to do it, and I don't know which one is best.

To list code that resides in a separate file, you can either (a) use the tcbinputlisting command or (b) wrap the inputminted command in a tcolorbox environment.

To list code that is put into the LaTeX source itself, you can either (a) use the tcblisting environment or (b) wrap the minted environment in a tcolorbox.

Is it better to use (a) or (b)? Is one more capable than the other? If not, which method is considered most modern, clean and nice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, the core of the question is: Should I use

- (a) the macros provided by the `minted` library of `tcolorbox`,
- (b) the base `tcolorbox` package without the `minted` library but with the macros from the `minted` package.

The answer will depend on your special application and will also be opinion-based to a certain degree, but I will try to give the pros and cons.

**(a) Using the `minted` library of `tcolorbox`:**

- *Pro:* The library provides shortcut macros which allow to write a compact source code. The option settings for `minted` are melted into the `tcolorbox` options which allows common settings (you may call that *clean*). New boxed listings (numbered or not) are created easily by the environment creation macros of the library. There is special support, if the minted code is a LaTeX source which should be also be displayed compiled.
- *Con:* The library macros enwraps the `minted` macros which may hide some (future) functionality of `minted`. The box content is filled automatically; individual mixtures of e.g. source+text+source are not covered.

**(b) Using the base `tcolorbox` plus macros from the `minted` library.**

- *Pro:* Full flexibility for the box content. All (future) `minted` capabilities can be used directly.
- *Con:* Longer and more complex source code. Option settings for `tcolorbox` and `minted` have to be done separately.

Why was the `minted`/`listings` library created? Because I had tons of examples using the (b) method which all had the same ever-repeating structure. With the library, they are much shorter and better readable. But, my examples mostly contained source code plus compiled text; there, the advantage is greater than just displaying source code.

**Finally:** There is no need to use either (a) or (b). Both can be used in parallel. I use the (a) method for most cases. If a box needs more flexibility (e.g. two source codes in one box), I switch to (b) for this box.